# Magento 2.2: Why some images can be displayed from phtml and some cannot?

Tags: image, phtml, magento2.2

Below are four examples of images randomly taken from the Net, two are displaying properly with in custom theme template using `<img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('publicite1.jpg'); ?>" />` but two others won't be displayed by Magento:

**Images not being displayed:**

- http://www.webdo.tn/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/publicite1.jpg
- http://fr.learnlayout.com/images/logo.png

The value in the browser developer tool inspector for these images is `<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/pub/static/version1510292523/frontend/Myvendor/mytheme/en_US/images/publicite1.jpg" style="display: none !important;">`

**Images being displayed:**

- https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg
- https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg

What is the problem with these images not being displayed ?

**ADDENDUM:**

I noticed that it worked after changing the name of one of the images in `web/images` and in its path in the phtml file, but didn't work again when renaming it to the original name.

It seems the problem is coming from **Chrome** and **Firefox**, these images are displaying fine with **Safari** and **Vivaldi**. But cleaning the cache of **Chrome** and **Firefox** doesn't help. Maybe there's a *deep* cleaning function somewhere in these browsers ?

Comment: As per your code it shows that **http images are not working  
but images with source  https are working**  
is that right ?

Comment: Indeed, but what would be the link between the protocol of the websites where images come from and the images itself when they are already downloaded to `web/images` folder ?

Comment: you should remove this `style="display: none !important;"` from `<img>`

Comment: @maxagaz Ohh sorry I thought you are using images from the direct URL.

Comment: @Piyush I can't remove this style, it comes back as soon as I remove it.

Comment: image are being added but they are not visible due to that style, from browser debug tool remove that display:none and it will be visible

Comment: As I said earlier, it's not removable in the browser debug tool. It's written back by the browser as soon as it's deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guilty was **AdBlock**, installed on Firefox and Chrome. After disabling it, everything works fine.

All my images containing for instance `ad` or `advertising` were actually blocked by AdBlock by adding the css `<style="display: none !important;">`.